# Duplicate table view cell while dequeueing

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, duplicates

I know this has been asked thousands of times. But I am truly stumped here.

I have a custom table view cell that has been created using an xib.

```swift
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: MyCell.identifier, bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: MyCell.identifier)
```

In the `cellForRowAt` I am dequeuing it like so

```swift
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: MyCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as? MyCell
```

I have also implemented `prepareForReuse` in `MyCell`.

And still when I interact with the table view random number of times, the cells are duplicated. These are duplicate cells like for the indexPath (0,4), say, the `cellForRowAt` is called and returns a new cell. The subviews in the cell are not added multiple times.

Comment: What do you mean there are duplicate cells?  It is completely normal for `cellForRowAt` to be called multiple times for the same IndexPath multiple times as cells are reused

Comment: Right. But I am seeing multiple cells being added to the tableview. The model has not changed. The number of rows is the same.

Comment: I am wondering if I should look for memory leaks. Will an unused cell be queued if it still being retained somewhere?

Comment: You mean you are seeing duplicated rows in your tableview?

Comment: yes. There are 2 cells for the same index path - this happens for only one of the custom cell. I have other cells that are not behaving this way. The only diff between the 2 is this one is created using an xib and the others are done programmatically. Something is terrible going wrong.

Comment: It is impossible for the tableview itself to show two different cells for the same index path at the same time.  Can you show your `cellForRowAt` code?  Where/how are you adding views programatically?  Do you mean to say you are returning two different object types for the same re-use identifier?  That is a big no-no

Comment: Adding a symbolic breakpoint at `UITableViewAlertForVisibleCellsAccessDuringUpdate` helped me debug this issue.